Pulsar Package publishing
I have a repository on github, with Pulsar package.
I cloned the repo to PC, and trying to publish it, using pulsar -p publish minor, but if failes with message:
cd language-saturn
pulsar -p publish minor
Welcome to Pulsar!

Before you can publish packages, you'll need an API token.

Visit your account page on pulsar-edit.dev https://web.pulsar-edit.dev/users,
copy the token and paste it below when prompted.

Press [Enter] to open your account page. 
Token> *********************************
Saving token to Keychain ✓
Registering language-saturn ✗
Registering package in phyalexander/language-saturn repository failed: Server Error: From Bad Repo: Error: Unable to locate the tag for 'package.json' version '0.0.0'. Are you sure you published a matching tag?

package.json:
{
  "name": "language-saturn",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Saturn language syntax support in Atom/Pulsar",
  "engines": {
    "atom": "*"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/phyalexander/language-saturn.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/phyalexander/language-saturn/issues"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "phyalexander <phy.alex@mail.ru>"
}



Fixed by:

Create a tag with the version v0.1.0 in your repository using the command git tag v0.0.0
push the tag using git push --tags.

P.S. "Thanks" everybody for "answers"... Thanks to ChatGPT for working solution.

You can accept the answer to mark this as useful. And because SO don't allows AI-generated content, your P.S. may cause misunderstandings.
